# Linearizing by the Jacobian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

> A nonlinear second order differential equation $x^{\prime \prime}=x-x^{3}+2 x x^{\prime}$
> a) Translate this into a first order nonlinear system and determine its equilibrium points.
> b) Linearize about each equilibrium point and find the eigenvalues and describe the behavior of the equilibrium. For any point with real eigenvalues compute the two eigenvectors.
> c) Now use Maple to generate a phase plane diagram of the system. Put in a variety of initial conditions and study what happens. Write a paragraph on how different trajectories of this system behave and how it is related to the nature of the equilibrium points.

I am given this equation $x'' = x − x^3 + 2xx'$ and asked to translate it into a first order nonlinear equation and then to linearize about each equilibrium point.

I am unsure whether my translation was valid nor which two equations to use for the Jacobian.

I let $x_1=x$ and $x_2=x'$. I got $x_2'=x_1-(x_1^3)+2x_1x_2$ and $x_1'=x_2$ and my equilibrium points were $(0,0), (1,0),(-1,0)$.